# Sort Objects Of Class Which Has hasMany relationship

Tags: grails, grails-orm

I have Domains like this

```
class A{

String mainAddress
static hasMany = [Bs: B]
static mapping = {
 mainAddress formula: ('select ad.zip from B  ad where ad.a_id=id')
 }
}

Class B{
String zip
static belongsTo = [a: A]
}

let A1 ->B1
       ->B2
and A2 ->B3
       ->B4
    A3 ->B5
       ->B6
       etc..
```

Now I want to sort on the basis of zip Of B1, B3,B5 etc

**Edit**: I did some changes in question and then I try to access

```
  a.mainAddress
```

this gives null

Comment: What have you tried already? What's not working about what you have tried? Are you using a criteria? HQL? Raw SQL?

Comment: I was trying raw sql as formula.I will update within moment.

Comment: Then you should put that in your question, along with what the results were, what problems you were having with the result and ask for help with solving that problem. Otherwise, this question is too broad and is simply saying "Write the code for me."

Comment: I have updated my question what I have tried.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If I understood You, You want to sort B objects belongs to A object by zip, if so this code should work for You:

```
def a = .. instance of A object
def listOfB = a.Bs.sort{it.zip}
```

or if You want to sort it on database:

You should add another static mapping to Your B class http://grails.org/doc/2.4.3/ref/Database%20Mapping/sort.html :

```
static mapping =
{
    sort "zip"
    // or
    sort zip : "asc" // or "desc"
}
```

also the formula should be:

```
formula: '(select ad.zip from B  ad where ad.a_id=this.id)'
```

instead of:

```
formula: ('select ad.zip from B  ad where ad.a_id=id')
```

because You didn't specify id of which object You want to get.

Comment: There is small change required here '(select ad.zip from B  ad where ad.a_id=id)', quotes the query.

Comment: ... ad.a_id=id)' and it works without this.id instead of same id?